# Use react-router-dom to handle routes and links to ids

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom, and in order to prevent the entire page from refreshing as I navigate between routes I am using the NavLink component. This works fine for routes like '/contact', however it will not handle links to specific sections with ids, such as /contact#main. Is there a way to continue to use NavLink and still have the links to specific sections work?

Answer (score 3):

In react-router-dom You can use like

```
<Link
to={{
pathname: "/contact",
hash: "#main",
state: { ...}
}}
/>
```

Comment: This sets the route correctly in the url, but I am sent to the top of /contact, not to /contact#main. If I refresh the page, it loads to /contact#main.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known issue with the react-router library, and there is an additional library that can be added to resolve the issue:

[react-router-hash-link](https://github.com/rafrex/react-router-hash-link)